# What are the different kinds of computation that exist?

Tags: analytic-philosophy, computation

What are the different kinds of computation that exist? From what I can see, there are two kinds:

- Computation based on non-electric and analog devices: abacuses, human
  brain, calculator
- Computation based on digital devices: computers

I am wondering if there are more kinds of computation or whether philosophers use different criteria to distinguish between different kinds of computation.

Comment: To discuss a "kind of computation" you need to specify a category with respect to which the "kinds" are taken. The specific examples you give correspond not even to the computation itself but to its implementation, digital or analog. [Artificial neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) and [quantum computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing) implementations are arguably distinct from both. The classification intrinsic to computation itself is based on [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory).

Comment: @Conifold Don't neural nets run on perfectly conventional hardware? They're a clever way of organizing a computation, but they're no different in principle than a spreadsheet or word processor. The idea of weighting nodes is not new, it's an old optimization technique. Likewise quantum computers offer no improvement in what can be computed. As you admit, the only difference is in efficiency. Complexity is not computability, and the computational limits of Turing machines have not been breached in any way.

Comment: Computing using pencil and paper methods or an abacus is not different in principle from using a classical electronic computer, so I don't see why we would call it a different kind of computation. The difference is just speed. Quantum computers can solve problems in a different complexity class to those solvable by a classical computer: there is evidence that BQP is a strict superset of PH. Analog computers are quite different, but ultimately they run into limitations of precision of measurement and they require calibration, which make them inconvenient and impractical.

Comment: Do you do the computations with pencil or pen?  Paper or animal hides?  Left-to-right, right-to-left, top-to-bottom, bottom-to-top?

Comment: @Bumble Quantum computers give absolutely no improvement in computability, only in complexity. I hope you agree. Anything that a quantum computer can compute can already be computed by a classical one. The proof is that quantum computers can be simulated (albeit slowly) by classical ones.

Comment: @user4894 That there is no difference in what can be computed is correct, that there is no difference in principle is not. All conventional computations are input/output equivalent to computations on a Turing machine by the Church-Turing thesis, but the Turing machine only emulates other types of computers, it does not simulate them. Computations are differently structured. Similarly, neither neural networks nor quantum computers can be simulated on conventional von Neumann computers, only emulated. One can take a bus or a plane to work and get there, but a bus is not a plane.

Comment: @Conifold A bus is not a plane? Ok you earned a chuckle from me but you failed to make a point. You are essentially agreeing with me. Your distinction between emulation and simulation is totally unclear in this context. You can *implement* a quantum algorithm or a neural net on a pencil-and-paper Turing machine if you like.

Comment: @user4894 I doubt you think you can get the functioning of a quantum computer by inspecting operations of a Turing machine. But it is a common mistake to read into Church-Turing thesis more than it actually says. You can implement some paper-and-pencil algorithms on a Turing machine, more or less, but you have to rewrite the algorithm altogether to adapt it to the functioning of qubits or neurons, which can only be "imitated" on it in some abstract sense. It is a different algorithm even if it computes the same thing, the transformation changes the structure of computations.

Comment: @Conifold Quantum computers are regularly implemented on conventional hardware. Computationally, there is no difference. The only difference is in efficiency, ie complexity class, on *certain classes* of problems, not even on all problems. Changing the "structure" of a computation does not affect whether something is computable or not. You're wrong on this one and I suspect you realize that. There are many algorithms to compute a given computable function. Means nothing in the present context. Shor's algorithm factors integers in poly time, but factorization is classically computable. Right?

Comment: @Conifold The distinction you're trying to make is like saying that using a loop versus using recursion is a "different mode of computation," and that you might not be able to discern the difference by examining the raw machine code. It's a weak and specious argument. The mere fact that it's not always easy to reverse-engineer machine code does not mean you have invented a new type of computation. Causitive gave an answer enumerating the actual types of computation recognized in computer science. All other responses here miss the point. If OP wanted something else they should have asked.

Comment: @user4894 The distinction b/w informational and computational equivalence is not mine, it is commonly used in cognitive science (Simon and Larkin) and analysis of modeling (Nersessian). If there was "no difference" we could not have different algorithms with the same input/output (and even of the same complexity), or different proofs of the same theorem. So the question for you is this: what is it that makes different algorithms for computing the same function different, and what is it that makes algorithms employing different sets of base operations "the same"?

Comment: I think so far we are talking past each other. The crude classification of algorithms by input/output match that CTT provides and that you are talking about (i.e. whether something is computable), is of little interest for most purposes. A finer equivalence requires step by step conversion that preserves the structure of operations, and such conversion is not forthcoming when one base set (von Neumann architecture) involves rewrites of digital memory and the other (neural nets) has no such thing. All you can have is abstract imitation of one on the other, which is a CTT triviality.

Comment: @Conifold The OP used the word computation. Nothing you say is of any relevance beyond that. If they meant complexity or efficiency they could well have said that. If they didn't know the difference, people could have explained it to them, rather than further obscuring it as you have chosen to do. Computation is as Turing defined it in 1936. You ask what makes algorithms that compute the same thing different, well some are more efficient. I'm sure we agree on that.

Comment: @user4894 It seems to me that you obscured the issue by first insisting that computations, as Turing defined them, can only be classified one way, and then contradicting yourself and admitting that they can also be classified in another, finer, way, by complexity/efficiency. Generally, a class of items, computations or others, does not come with a single category according to which it can be classified. Nor do input/output and complexity exhaust possible categories for computations. Finer classifications are in use and are not disqualified simply because you happen to be unfamiliar with them.

Comment: @Conifold You are really reaching. There's only one way to categorize things? Cats and human are mammals, and within that category, humans are primates and cats are felidae. I'm usually impressed by your writing but I am baffled by your disingenuous remarks on this subject I contradicted myself by pointing out the distinction between computability and complexity? Me and Scott Aaronson and every computer scientist in the world. I'm in good company. I cannot for the life of me follow your thought process. Exp and poly are NOT distinct modes of computation; they're equally computable.

Comment: @Conifold Equally computable; different complexity. What baffles me is that *you know this* but for some reason won't acknowledge it.

Comment: @user4894 The question is what one counts to make modes of computation distinct, and that depends on one's purpose. I am struggling to understand why you think computability to be the only way to do it, is it because the words have the same root? Even computer scientists classify computations in different ways, that's why we have different "styles" of programming. I do not follow where your charges of reaching and disingenuity are coming from, and I am surprised by your seeming inability to grasp elementary things, it's like tunnel vision. I am not sure what you wish me to acknowledge either.

Comment: " I am struggling to understand why you think computability to be the only way to do it," -- I am struggling to understand why you put words in my mouth that I have not said, representing ideas I do not espouse, and doing so in such a wholly disingenuous manner. I don't think this is going anywhere. You have not made your point with me, and furthermore unlike instances where if I don't agree with someone's point I can at least understand it; in this case I don't understand your point at all. Thanks for the chat. See you on some other thread. You can have the last word if you like.

Comment: @Conifold ps I see I called you disingenuous again after you complained about my doing that. What can I say, it's how it seems to me. I grasp elementary things quite well, hence my position here. Even a few advanced things sometimes.

Comment: @user4894 I only regret not finishing it sooner, when you started imputing bad faith for a point you say you do not understand. For the future, mind reading over the internet works badly, and comment discussions are more constructive without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Types of computation are not based on the type of device but on the way in which information is structured and processed. The principal types are analogue, digital and quantum. (What follows is updated following comments and downvotes made).

For example an abacus is a digital (ON/OFF) computer, albeit using decimal word lengths rather than bit-count word lengths. Some early electronic computers used the same decimal system, as did Babbage's mechanical Difference Engine of the late 19th century. A box of counters, a pencil and a sheet of paper are an even simpler, though rather more flexible, digital computer. Powerful ones just happen to be electronic these days.

By contrast an analogue computer processes signals (numbers) which are continuously variable across the working range. Analogue computers have been mechanical as in the computing gunsights fitted to American bombers in WWII, electrical as in some early aircraft control systems, or even hydraulic as in the first ever computational model of the UK economy.

A quantum computer operates on a third principle again. Where a digital process is discrete and analog is continuous, a quantum process is a superposition of all possibilities. A quantum computer typically comprises a set of components called qbits, which are linked or entangled together in such a way as to collectively processes a near-infinite superposition of intangible possibilities before they find the most likely answer. Other more exotic quantum architectures also exist, which are not bound by the "bit" model necessary to communicate with a discrete-logic controller. Although the quantum processor is surrounded by a conventional digital control system, the core processor itself is anything but digital. These devices are at a very early stage of development and to say more requires a degree in advanced ... - you know, I don't even know what you do need to know.

The human or animal brain is, broadly speaking, an analogue device in terms of its chemistry but digital in the way it encodes nerve signals as pulse trains. Nobel prize-winning physicist and mathematician Roger Penrose is among those who have argued that neural processing, especially memory, also depends on quantum phenomena.

A neural network is a technological architecture which seeks to emulate certain features of human brain activity. Neural networks are commonly used for AI applications involving big data and deep learning. Typically, at some point a digital device will be used to simulate an analogue function (which is itself an approximation of the original neural digital pulse train). Theoretically an analogue device known as a memristor would greatly improve circuit efficiency, but only experimental memristor-like circuit modules have yet been developed. Working systems remain all-digital emulations.

Comment: Quantum computers and neural networks can be implemented on classical computers. Quantum computers are so implemented as proof of concept; and neural nets *always* are. They do not constitute new types of computing, any more than laptops over keypunch machines do. OP asked about computation, not complexity classes.

Comment: @user4894 Sorry, but that is nonsense. They can be simulated to a useful but limited degree, but we would not be developing devices and circuits on fundamentally new technological and computational principles if they were just subsets of Boolean space. Quantum supremacy of a qbit system over its digital simulation has already been demonstrated, and memristor-function modules are also available in experimental quantities.

Comment: You're just misinformed or wrong. Nothing can be computed by a quantum computer that can not already be computed on a classical one. The proof, which I already explained, is that one can implement a quantum computer on a conventional one. There are differences in *complexity class* for a limited set of problems such as integer factorization. But there is no increase in computation ability. You are confusing complexity with computability. In the case of neural nets the case is even more clear because neural nets are ALWAYS implemented on conventional computers.

Comment: ps -- Quantum supremacy is a concept of *complexity*, not computability. It refers to how efficiently a computation can be done; for example, the difference between polynomial time and exponential time. Both are computable, but as the size of the input grows, exponential problems take longer and longer to run. As a striking example, Shor's algorithm is a quantum algorithm to factor integers in polynomial time. That's a fantastic breakthrough; but it does NOT offer any improvement in computability; only in complexity. If someone found a mode of computation beyond the Turing machine it would be

Comment: (cont) a world-shaking breakthrough that would violate the Church-Turing thesis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis. This has not happened at all. Anything a quantum computer can compute can already be computed with pencil and paper by a person emulating a Turing machine, a model of computation created in 1936 by Turing and *never exceeded*. I hope you will come to appreciate these points as the breathless quantum and AI hype trains roll down the tracks. Both are perfectly classical computations in the sense of Turing.

Comment: @user4894 Your ramble is not what comments are for, you should give your own answer. I will say that quantum computing involves phenomena such as superposition and entanglement. It is in no way not equivalent to standard logic, for example a qubit may be in a superposition of 0 and 1 states with only a probabilistic outcome, while other more exotic forms of quantum computation exist. Comparable issues arise with neural processing; Nobel prize-winning mathematician Roger Penrose asserts that it is qualitatively distinct. I'd suggest you check such matters out before you post that answer.

Comment: Why should I give an answer, you've already earned the checkmark. Quick checkmarks to wrong answers are one of the problems with this site. Quick checkmarks in general preclude others from answering; and checkmarks to wrong answers confuse everybody, especially the OP as has happened here. I'm disappointed that you refuse to acknowledge the distinction between computability and complexity. In no effing way does Penrose think quantum computers disprove the Church-Turing thesis. You keep doubling and tripling down on your misconceptions. There is no Nobel prize in mathematics, of course.

Comment: Still wrong after your edits. Neural nets and quantum computers can be implemented as Turing machines. If not, you'd have heard about it. It would be a huge revolutionary discovery. Are you claiming the Church-Turing thesis has been falsified? If so, you better provide me a link. If not, your claims stand falsified.

Comment: @user4894. Checkmarks are not eternal. If you provide a better answer, the OP is at liberty to change their mind. I am sure we would all be grateful if you turned your energies more positively in that direction, rather than continue abusing the comments system. Meanwhile, you might like to recall that the Church-Turing issue is not related to the mode of computation, which latter is the subject of the original question.

Comment: Better answers have been provided by those with more CS knowledge than I possess. But thanks for caring.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are different kinds of *physical computers* as the other answer touched on.  But if you're asking about types of *computation*, then in mathematics and computer science this often refers to formal systems that are able to calculate different classes of functions.  See the article on [automata theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) which highlights four important models of computation, and then goes on to describe a lot more.

- [Combinational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinational_logic) corresponds to Boolean expressions, or functions that can be calculated by a single pass through a feed-forward logic circuit.
- [Finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) are computers with only a finite set of internal states and a finite possible set of inputs.  After each input, a finite state machine changes to a new state, depending on its current state and the input.  They can tell whether a string is part of a specific "regular language" - similar to what a regex can do.
- [Pushdown automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) are computers with a finite state machine that can also interact with a stack of unlimited size.  A pushdown automaton can only push or pop the top element of the stack, it can't look at an element below the top without popping the elements above it first.  Pushdown automata can tell whether a string is part of a context free language.
- [Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) are computers with a finite state machine that can interact with a tape of unlimited size.  A Turing machine can read or write to the "current" tape cell, or it can move the current tape cell left or right.

These are four important and common models of computation, but there are more.  There are the [primitive recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) which can calculate anything a pushdown automaton can calculate, but can't calculate as much as a Turing machine.  There are [hypercomputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation) and [oracle machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine) which are more powerful than Turing machines, but cannot be physically implemented as far as we know.  There are also many models of computation that are equivalent to some already mentioned, many of which are laid out in the article on automata theory.  Some examples are lambda calculus, combinatory logic, cellular automata, non-deterministic Turing machines, Post canonical systems.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. This is the response that should be checkmarked, as it's the correct answer.